# reactjs-How to pass a state element to child without reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the above code,if  `x` in `control` it is reflected in `display`.How to pass an element of a parent component's (i.e `control`) state so that change in parent's state will not affect the child (i.e `display`)?

```
class Display extends React.Component{
    render()
    {
        return( <button>{this.props.x}</button> );
    }
}

class Control extends React.Component{

        state={
            x:'Hello'
            }
            
        render()
        {
        const {x}=this.state;

        return(  <Display x={x}/> );

        }
}
```

Comment: Btw, React component names should be capitalized. `return ( <display x={x}/> );` should be `return ( <Display x={x}/> );` with corresponding changes to the declarations for class control and class display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. You can assign the prop value to an 'instance' variable in componentDidMount. ComponentDidMount will run only once, when `Display` first mounts. In the example below, it will assign the value of `this.props.x` to `this.x`. Using `this.something` creates an 'instance' variable that will be available anywhere in `Display`. It will not be updated/changed when this.props.x changes (assuming x is a primitive value like a string or number). And if you change the value of `this.x` it will not cause a rerender of `Display`.

```
class Display extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
      this.x = this.props.x;
    }

    render()
    {
        return( <button>{this.x}</button> );
    }
}

class Control extends React.Component{

        state={
            x:'Hello'
            }
            
        render()
        {
        const {x}=this.state;

        return(  <Display x={x}/> );

        }
}
```

Comment: How can I  "copy"  an element from state to a variable and pass that variable to child so that changes won't be reflected?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question initially. If you pass `x` from parent's state to the child, then in componentDidMount() you can do `this.x = props.x`, then use `this.x` elsewhere in child. The value of `this.x` will not be updated when the value of `props.x` changes.

Comment: Could you please show some code? I am just learning react.

Comment: Updated my answer with example code. Hope it helps.